# No expected output when accessing variable from one function and using in another fucntion

Tags: qgis, pyqgis, qgis-plugins, python-2.7

I have a function say selectedfeatures this function would be called when a selection changed event happens in mapcanvas.

```
self.canvas.selectionChanged.connect(self.selectedfeatures)
QObject.connect(self.dlg.runbutton, SIGNAL("clicked()"), self.mapselection)

def selectedfeatures(self):
    layer = iface.activeLayer()
    idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')
    self.feature = layer.selectedFeatures()
    QMessageBox.information(self.dlg, "features were selected:",  str(len(self.feature)) + " features were selected " +"" )
```

And for that selected features in the above function i want to perform buffer using the below function.I am using the self.feature in mapselection function like below

```
    def mapselection (self):
        for feature in self.feature:
         mbuf = feature.geometry().buffer(dist, 2)
         iterFeat = layer.getFeatures()
         for f in iterFeat:
             geom2 = f.geometry()
             valTest = QgsGeometry.within(geom2, mbuf)
             if valTest:
                idx = feature.fieldNameIndex('name')  #name of the attribute column with the cities in it
                idx1 = feature.fieldNameIndex('state')
                nearCity = f.attributes()[idx]
                state = f.attributes()[idx1]
                state_and_cities = str(state) + "," + str(nearCity)
                lsNearCities.append(state_and_cities) 
                #call the function to write them into a file
            self.writeToFile(lsNearCities, filePath)
```

The output is not as expected though there are features selected in mapcanvas, it is saying 0 cities were there in the list lsNearCities.I want to know should i want to include any event separately for selection process completed in mapcanvas? If so how should that be done? Please tell me where i am wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keep things simple, you don't need a special function `selectedfeatures` here, you can do everything at once (try your script in the Python console before).

1) you don't need the `Valtest`and `state_and_cities` variables:

```
layer = iface.activeLayer()
idx = layer.fieldNameIndex('name')
idx1 = feature.fieldNameIndex('state')
for feature in layer.selectedFeatures():
    mbuf = feature.geometry().buffer(dist, 2)
    for f in layer.getFeatures():
        geom2 = f.geometry()
        if QgsGeometry.within(geom2, mbuf):
             lsNearCities.append(str(f.attributes()[idx]) + "," + str(f.attributes()[idx1]))
```

2) If you want to further simplify (only one for loop), use the [itertools](https://docs.python.org/2/library/itertools.html) standard Python module.

```
import itertools
for f, feature in itertools.product(layer.getFeatures(), layer.selectedFeatures()):
   geom2 = f.geometry()
   mbuf = feature.geometry().buffer(dist, 2)
   if QgsGeometry.within(geom2, mbuf):
       lsNearCities.append(str(f.attributes()[idx]) + "," + str(f.attributes()[idx1]))
 self.writeToFile(lsNearCities, filePath)
```

3) And you can do that without `lsNearCities`:

```
with open(filepath, 'w') as output:
    for f, feature in itertools.product(layer.getFeatures(), layer.selectedFeatures()):
       geom2 = f.geometry()
       mbuf = feature.geometry().buffer(dist, 2)
           if QgsGeometry.within(geom2, mbuf):
               output.write(str(f.attributes()[idx]) + "," + str(f.attributes()[idx1])+ '\n')
```